# Why we use MDC.remove() in Logback/SLF4J?

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback, mdc

I know that MDC is used in client server, logging in order to find out which log is for which client. ([reference](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html))

But why we use `MDC.remove()`?

Is it a memory efficiency issue?

Answer (score 3):

Another reason is that the value is out-of-date. For example, if you have an username in MDC but the user is already logged out you have an outdated information. It could mislead debugging completely if you still log this.

Comment: well that is a good prespective, but as far as i know MDC is for clearifying which client made whcih log statement,but if a client is already logged out so no more logging will happen and we dont have any misleading log messages!!

Comment: @user3593084: Consider that case when a client can see the main page with and without logging in and the application log that. In the latter case (without logging in) the log message should not contain the username.

Comment: i dont understand a client sees the page without logging, so it cant do any-thing so no logging would happen !

Comment: @user3593084: I don't understand completely what you don't understand :) Anyway, the example could be a little bit confusing because of "logging in" (authenticating with a user/pass) and "log" (writing messages to a file) are different things.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a put() operation should be balanced by the corresponding remove() operation. Otherwise, the MDC will contain stale values for certain keys. We would recommend that whenever possible, remove() operations be performed within finally blocks, ensuring their invocation regardless of the execution path of the code.